# Remove or hide a div if it's empty

Tags: jquery

I know this should be simple but can't figure it out. Here's the code.

```
<div class="cols lmenu_item1" id="leftMenuWrapper">
<div id="leftmenu"></div>
</div>
```

I simply need to remove the "leftMenuWrapper" if "leftmenu" is empty. Here's what I've been using.

```
$('#leftmenu').empty().remove('#leftMenuWrapper');
```

Sorry if this is a simple question. Having a Monday!

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327751/hide-divs-if-they-are-empty

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#leftmenu:empty').parent().remove();
```

This only selects `#leftmenu` *if* it's [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/), and then only grabs the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) of *that* to [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).  If it wasn't empty, then the first selector won't find anything, or any parent to remove either.

Comment: Who said scripting wasn't elegant?

Comment: @Peter - I think next to `:animated` and `:header` it's the most under-utilized of the really handy pseudo-selectors out there, give them some love!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove if it **looks** empty:

```
if ( $.trim( $('#leftmenu').text() ) == "")
    $('#leftMenuWrapper').remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FSkV5/)**

The above takes just the text contents of `#leftmenu` and trims off the whitespace before checking if anything's there.

The big advantage of the above over `$(#leftmenu:empty)` is that the above removes in the following cases where `:empty` would not:

```
                  // The above code works in these cases where ":empty" does not:

<div id="leftmenu">     </div>                              // <== white space
<div id="leftmenu"><p></p></div>                            // <== empty elements
```

**[.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)**
**[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**
**[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)**

---

Note that the following is more efficient (but less readable imo):

```
var $elie = ('#leftmenu');
if ( $.trim( $elie.text() ) == "")
    $elie.parent().remove();
```

Comment: +1 - I'll bet a lot of people get stuck when `:empty` doesn't work because there a space or line break.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Looking at your jsFiddle page and the #leftMenuWrapper containing the text "You will see this, if it hasn't been removed." has been removed. But from what I can tell, your script is supposed to only remove the #leftMenuWrapper if there is no text inside...???

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$('#leftmenu').html()){ $('#leftmenu').parent().remove(); }
```

Comment: This would seem to work, but it is not quite as efficient because you're having to select the element twice. Certainly seems like a valid solution, though.

Comment: @patrick - I guess you could do `var $elie = $('#leftmenu'); if(!$elie.html()){ $elie.parent().remove(); }`

Comment: @Peter - Very true. Would be much better to cache the result of the selector. In fact, for an element with an ID that gets selected more than once anywhere, I'd probably cache it.