# How can I hide divs if they are empty?

Tags: jquery

I have some divs that maybe be empty (depending on server-side logic).

```
<div id="bar">

<div class="section" style="display:block;"></div>
<div class="section" style="display:block;"></div>
<div class="section" style="display:block;"></div>

</div>
```

If they don't have any html inside the div's (with class section), I just want to hide them.

How can I do this?

Comment: As you can see many solutions are available. It would be a good thing for you to go through each to see how they work and see their differences if any.

Comment: As you mention server-side logic, the most efficient way would be not to render them if they have no content (e.g. <?php if(content!="") { ?><div class="section" style="display:block;"></div><?php } ?>.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

jQuery has a [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector.  So, you can simply do:

```
$('div.section:empty').hide();
```

Comment: @Beaniie: What do you mean by "PHP markup"?  PHP code runs on the *server* and generates output that's sent to the browser.  So, if the PHP code outputs anything then the `<div>` wouldn't be empty.

Comment: By my understanding a div collapses when it is empty and has auto height. However, adding PHP markup to a div is different in the sense a broswer first recognises that something is in that div when it loads. Even though after page load there is nothing in that div, it doesn't fully collapse.

Comment: Expanding on my last - `<div><?php echo "flagErr"; ?></div>` This div is empy on page load but isn't fully collapsed, only when the page finds an error, the div populates with text. I'm only left to beleive that the php code is interpreted as text, and then recognised as code. But of this I'm unsure....

Comment: @Beaniie: If the PHP code is "interpreted as text", then something is wrong on your server and the PHP code isn't being ran.  What's probably happening is that you are getting `<div>\t\t\t</div>` or something (excess whitespace, which I thought *was* collapsed), which *may* be seen as non-empty.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: Through testing I have discovered that the php is working fine and no issues are arising except for the div not collapsing on load. I find it strange as the div is empty on load, but after form submission and bad data is discovered the php populates a notification in that div. The php appears fine its the HTML markup in my eyes that is acting strangely.

Answer (score 27):

Here is a CSS3 solution for anyone who is interested

```
div:empty {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution but does not always work https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/

Comment: Wow amazing, nice find!

Answer (score 6):

There are many options, it all depends on what your preferences are.
The more compact the answer the less readable it becomes, is speed important, and how effective should the empty function be, an element containing no nodes is not the same as an `:empty` element.

**Most compact / Slow / Very Effective  / readable / generic selector**

```
$('.section:empty').hide();
```

**Very compact / little faster (still Slow) / Very Effective / readable / less generic selector**

```
$('div.section:empty').hide();
```

**Compact  / Faster / Very Effective / readable / specific selector**

```
$("#bar").find('div.section:empty').hide();
```

I'm Going to stick with the more specifc selector as it is faster.

**Less Compact / Even Faster / Very Effective / still less readable**

```
$("#bar").find('div.section').filter(function(i,elem) {

    for ( elem = elem.firstChild; elem; elem = elem.nextSibling ) {
        if ( elem.nodeType < 6 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}).hide();
```

**Still Less Compact / Even Faster Still / Very Effective / still less readable**

```
$("#bar").find('div.section').each(function(i,elem){

    for ( elem = elem.firstChild; elem; elem = elem.nextSibling ) {
        if ( elem.nodeType < 6 ) {
            return;
        }
    }
    $(this).hide();        
})
```

**Compact-ish / Much Faster / Less Effective / less readable**

```
// Faster Still but less precise
$("#bar").find('div.section').filter(function() {
    return !this.firstChild; 
}).hide();
```

**Less Compact / Much Faster Still / Less Effective / less readable**

```
$("#bar").find('div.section').each(function(){
    if(!this.firstChild){
        $(this).hide();            
    }           
})
```

**Effective Solution**

The more Effective Solutions use the same approach used by the 'empty' [jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.0.0-alpha1/dist/jquery.js#L1928) filter, it tries to replicate the functionality of the CSS3 `:empty` pseudo-class by taking into account the nodeType.
For example if a child element had nodeType == `COMMENT_NODE`(`<!-- -->`) then the parent will still be seen as empty.

All of these Approaches could be improved by replacing the `.hide()` with `.addClass('hide')` and adding a `.hide` class to your CSS.

```
<style>
    .hide {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

but if this sounds like an appropriate solution for you then  [@elliot-wood 's CSS3 Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17290875/2273611) is probably better suited.

#### My personal preference

```
$("#bar").find('div.section').filter(function() {
    return !this.firstChild; 
}).hide();
```

Even though this approach doesn't check nodeType and it uses `.filter()` method rather than the faster `.each()`. It is just a more compact and readable solution.

Answer (score 4):

Why does nobody use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) ?

```
$("div.section").filter(function() {
    return this.childNodes.length === 0;
}).hide();
```

This is a more elegant solution compared to using `.each`.

Answer (score 4):

If div contains white-space or line breaks then this code may be helpful...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   str = $('div.section').text();
   if($.trim(str) === "") {
     $('div.section').hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').each(function() {
if($(this).html().size() == 0) $(this).remove();
});
```

If you want to use the divs later on in the same page, it's better to use `$(this).hide();` instead of `$(this).remove();` as the divs will be deleted if you use remove();

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to server logic?

Else client side you could do something like:

```
$(function() {
$('div').each(function() {
       if ($(this).html()=="") {
             $(this).hide();
       }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and I advise : `$(this).html().trim() == ""`

Answer (score 0):

replace `display:block;` by `display: none;`

edit: Oh, i saw you wanted to use jQuery, then use .hide(): http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.section:empty').css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the filtering answer, but this.childNodes.length kept returning 1 also when there was no visible content, so ended up combining filter with trim.

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return j(this).text().trim() === "";
}).hide();
```