# Hide button for modal if {{ value[#] }} empty

Tags: jquery, if-statement, flask, datatables, jinja2

I'm currently working on a web interface for Excel reports relating to stock in a warehouse using Flask. I've built a table using DataTables that pulls data from a csv file and it's working away. 
I've been asked to add in an extra data cell at the end of each row which has a clickable button to open notes if a note exists on the csv file for that stock item. 
I'm trying to use a Font Awesome icon for the user to click to open a modal which shows the note however I cannot get the icon to only appear when there is a note to view.

Here's what I've tried

```
<tbody>                     
    {% for value in stocklist %}
    <tr>
       <td value="{{ value[12] }}"><p class="muted hidden">{{ value[12] }}</p></td>                        
       <td>{{ value[0] }}</td>
       <td>{{ value[2] }}</td>
       <td class="over-25">{{ value[4] }}</td>
       <td>{{ value[6] }}</td>
       <td>{{ value[7] }}</td>
       <td>{{ value[8] }}</td>
       <td>{{ value[9] }}</td>
       <td>{{ value[10] }}</td>
       <td>{{ value[11] }}</td>
       <td id="notes"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning hide_show" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i></button></td>
     </tr>                                       
     {% endfor %}

     {% for value in stocklist %}
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header ml-2">                                    
                       <h4 class="modal-title">Notes</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                       <p>{{ value[13] }}</p>                                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer ml-2">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
     {% endfor %}                       
</tbody>
```

And here is the jQuery I've tried -

```
$("#notes").find('hide_show').filter(function() {
return !this.firstChild; 
}).hide();
```

I have based my attempt off this answer --> [Hide div's if they are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327751/hide-divs-if-they-are-empty)

The other issue I have is that when the modal opens, it shows the same note (the note for stock item number 1) for each stock item regardless.

How do I get the icon to only appear when there is a note and then get the correct note to appear in the modal when opened?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: Not the solution, but you're using the id="notes" and id="myModal" multiple times as you write them in for-loops. ids have to be unique. Better change to classes instead.

Comment: Thanks for your replay Matthias. That's something I've been toying around with too and as yet, nothing has worked unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out!

I added the following -->

```
{% if value[13] is number %}
<td></td>
  {% else %}
    <td>The icon I wanted to display</td>
 {% endif %}
```

On the csv file, if there is no note for the stock item, it will autofill to 0 so it doesn't render the icon so nothing to click.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the notes data in the pulled value. I have no idea how you are pulling the data but this is a hint

```
{% if value.notes %}

<td id="notes"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning hide_show" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i></button>
</td>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi Tejiri and thank you for your reply. Here is the route I am using for the data --> 
        
        def csv_file():
            
            filename = 'static/critical_stock_categories.csv'
            
            data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0)

            stocklist = list(data.values)

            return render_template('csv-table.html', stocklist=stocklist)
Using your suggestion I went with {% if value[13] %} but it hasn't changed anything. Every table row has an icon to click and brings you to a modal with the exact same note as every other stock item