# How to span CONTENT over ASIDE if this last is empty

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap 3 layout, that is mainly 2-columns wide. A NAV column on the left (with class "`col-sm-3`") and a CONTENT column on the right (with class "`col-sm-9`").

```
<nav class='col-sm-3'>
  ...
</nav>
<article class='col-sm-9'>
  ...
</nav>
```

I need to add also a third column, a SIDEBAR:

```
<nav class='col-sm-3'>
  ...
</nav>
<article class='col-sm-6'>
  ...
</nav>
<aside class='col-sm-3'>
  ...
</nav>
```

But my problem is that ASIDE is not always filled with content, so I would like that ARTICLE will span over space normally dedicated to ASIDE in case it is empty (something like replacing "`col-sm-6`" with "`col-sm-9`").

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do it though Bootstrap framework alone - you will need to introduce some Jquery. Take a look at - [Remove or hide a div if it's empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886046/remove-or-hide-a-div-if-its-empty)

You will need that div to be removed when empty and also add class to article div to increase col size. This is how I would do it.

Comment: I imagined a solution like this... but I hoped that could be a better solution.... :-(

Comment: That would be nice! I'm currently hiding empty divs using asp.net, but if you don't have it setup that way and simply from front end then there is no alternative